# VirtualBox guest OS internet access over host's configured proxy

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn

I have a Xubuntu 14.10 guest running within VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host. The host is connected to a wired network which requires a proxy to access the outside world. The host is also connected to a VPN. Everything on the host works as expected - Windows can access both the internet and IPs on the VPN. Using tracert I believe Windows bypassing the VPN when connecting to the outside world.

The Xubuntu guest is configured with a single NAT adapter so that it shares the host's VPN connection. The guest can access IPs over the VPN. However, the guest cannot access access the internet.

I'm not a network expert but it seems to me the guest should not need to know the proxy configuration if it is NATd to the host. If the host mediates all of the guest's network activity then the Windows system proxy should take care of everything. However, just in case I have tried setting up a proxy within the guest and it made no difference (it's entirely possible that I did this wrong as Xubuntu seems to require a proxy to be configured via environment variables).

Does this simply mean that I need to properly configure a proxy for the guest OS, or could there be some other problem here?

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: Pls post your routing table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The proxy is system-wide. It's configured in Windows' Network & Internet settings. I know it is system-wide because once the proxy is configured I can ping domains from cmd, while I cannot do this without the proxy configured.

No, this is not correct. I have just redone it myself:

```
  netsh winhttp set proxy MYPROXY
```

as per [this Technet page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us//library/cc731131(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_5). This allowed me to ping whatever I wanted (Google's 8.8.8.8) even though I set MYPROXY to a non-existent proxy,which should not have allowed anything thru (BTW, I used `www.nytimes.com` for this).

**-->>** The reason why pings do not reach their intended targets, in your work place, if you have **not** set the proxy correctly, is that you have an aptly configured firewall in your LAN. it is not by chance that the command is `netsh` **winhttp**.

My initial point stands: the proxy you wish to configure for your guest will have to be setup within your guest browser. Then it will make no difference whether you connect via NAT or Bridge adapter, except for VPN, of course.

Comment: The proxy *is* system-wide. It's configured in Windows' Network & Internet settings. I know it is system-wide because once the proxy is configured I can ping domains from cmd, while I cannot do this without the proxy configured. The guest OS also needs the proxy to be system-wide as Maven needs to download dependencies.

Comment: thanks. ubproxy worked to configure the guest's proxy settings. I am unsure why my initial manual attempts to configure did not work as expected